# How to generate jti ( JWT Id) in java script?

Tags: jwt, uniqueidentifier, mirth, epic

To fetch EPIC data through mirth I want to create JWT so I followed documentation https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=BackendOAuth2Guide.

I dont know to how to generate jti which is required field in payload.
There are no specific rules or steps available online to follow and generate jti. Please guide me.

I tried the accepted answers as viewers suggested
I tried generating jti  using the accepted answers here.

Got this  r9d2ex8zs for following code

```
return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter( function(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}).join('').substr(2,50);
```

Got this h75tvne5n00000000000000000  for following syntax

```
return ((Math.random().toString(36)+'00000000000000000').slice(2, 50)).slice(2, 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random string. No need for any dependencies or external API.
The function in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript/1349426#1349426) is fine for this use case.

Comment: Thank you I tried the accepted answers  and got 2 different results

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for generating the JWT and all of the necessary fields in the payload is to use a library. This will make the process simpler and less prone to error. You can find a variety of libraries in numerous languages [here](https://jwt.io/libraries).

If for some reason you can't or don't want to use a library, the `jti` is simply a unique identifier for the JWT while the JWT is active (i.e., before the `exp` timestamp). There are a couple of strategies you can use to generate it:

1. Use the [uuid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate a v4 UUID.
2. Use Math.random() multiplied by a very large number to generate a random integer. Something like `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000000)`.
3. Use an external API like [random.org](https://www.random.org) to get a random number or string.